# How to make fixed navbar top like w3school

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to make top fixed navbar like w3school.com? when i scroll down, the top navbar will fixed and the logo are not. how to do that with using bootstrap css framewok? is that only can use with w3.css ? i doubt about it. thank you!

```css
#logo {
    text-align: center;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>

<div id="logo">
  <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1"/>
</div>

<div id="nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-fixed-top">
      <li><a href="...">Fixed</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Fixed</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Fixed</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Fixed</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Fixed</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Fixed</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
  
  <p> i want the navbar fixed like w3school.com when it the scroll down until reach the image the navbar will fixed. sorry for bad english.  visit w3school to see the navbar fixed top </p>
```

Comment: man use sticky.js and make any element stick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what u want:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Navbar like w3schools</title>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  
    // Fixa navbar ao ultrapassa-lo
    var navbar = $('#navbar-main'),
      distance = navbar.offset().top,
        $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {
            navbar.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
           $("body").css("padding-top", "70px");
        } else {
            navbar.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            $("body").css("padding-top", "0px");
        }
    });
});
  </script>
  <style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
      .man{
        display:none;
      }
    }
    body { overflow-x: hidden;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div style="font-weight:bold;font-size:35px;font-family:cursive;padding:5px;left:15px" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4">w3schools<span style="color:green">.com</span></div>
  <div style="font-weight:lighter;font-size:25px;padding:5px;top:12px" class="man col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-6">The world's largest web developer site</div>
</div>
  
 
<nav id="navbar-main" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display-->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  
 <main class="container">
<p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id voluptatum sequi sunt asperiores eius, qui saepe tempore aliquam debitis distinctio officia optio unde perferendis fugiat sint quia consequuntur, placeat sed!</p>
   
<p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id voluptatum sequi sunt asperiores eius, qui saepe tempore aliquam debitis distinctio officia optio unde perferendis fugiat sint quia consequuntur, placeat sed!</p>
   
<p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id voluptatum sequi sunt asperiores eius, qui saepe tempore aliquam debitis distinctio officia optio unde perferendis fugiat sint quia consequuntur, placeat sed!</p>

<p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id voluptatum sequi sunt asperiores eius, qui saepe tempore aliquam debitis distinctio officia optio unde perferendis fugiat sint quia consequuntur, placeat sed!</p>
  
<p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id voluptatum sequi sunt asperiores eius, qui saepe tempore aliquam debitis distinctio officia optio unde perferendis fugiat sint quia consequuntur, placeat sed!</p>
   
<p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id voluptatum sequi sunt asperiores eius, qui saepe tempore aliquam debitis distinctio officia optio unde perferendis fugiat sint quia consequuntur, placeat sed!</p>
   
<p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id voluptatum sequi sunt asperiores eius, qui saepe tempore aliquam debitis distinctio officia optio unde perferendis fugiat sint quia consequuntur, placeat sed!</p>
   
<p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id voluptatum sequi sunt asperiores eius, qui saepe tempore aliquam debitis distinctio officia optio unde perferendis fugiat sint quia consequuntur, placeat sed!</p>
 
<p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id voluptatum sequi sunt asperiores eius, qui saepe tempore aliquam debitis distinctio officia optio unde perferendis fugiat sint quia consequuntur, placeat sed!</p>
</main> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Karl This is what u want

Answer (score 1):

Right, so you can't do this with just CSS, you'll want to use a sticky library of some kind. I'm using in this example [sticky-kit](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/).

```js
$("#nav").stick_in_parent();
```

```css
#logo {
    text-align: center;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.sticky-kit/1.1.2/jquery.sticky-kit.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="logo">
  <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1"/>
</div>

<div id="nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="...">Fixed</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Fixed</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Fixed</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Fixed</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Fixed</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">Fixed</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
  
  <p> i want the navbar fixed like w3school.com when it the scroll down until reach the image the navbar will fixed. sorry for bad english.  visit w3school to see the navbar fixed top Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec non arcu sed nisl vehicula gravida. Donec arcu ante, consectetur ut neque et, finibus dignissim magna. Nam vitae felis porta, scelerisque diam ac, tristique felis. Ut id lectus diam. Fusce vel felis eu arcu porta imperdiet. Suspendisse justo velit, ultricies ut ultrices vel, mollis et elit. Maecenas at pharetra arcu, sed vestibulum urna. Donec a consectetur elit.

Ut nisl nisi, blandit sed tellus ac, vulputate posuere ex. Integer rutrum massa vel tincidunt lobortis. Donec eget rhoncus nisi. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus sed turpis hendrerit, maximus metus eleifend, sollicitudin enim. Donec ac congue ante. Praesent mi risus, auctor ac imperdiet non, iaculis id risus. Ut viverra et velit eget luctus. Mauris eu aliquam nisl. Nullam auctor augue id justo volutpat, nec consectetur neque volutpat.

Integer et urna tellus. Donec a fringilla erat. Nam ex urna, consequat ut sodales ut, congue in sem. Maecenas et tortor risus. Suspendisse maximus felis mauris. Duis porttitor mi eu finibus eleifend. Mauris ac pulvinar leo. Phasellus hendrerit faucibus sagittis. Donec rhoncus mattis lacinia. Nullam pulvinar urna at leo aliquam lacinia. Phasellus fringilla, augue eget posuere elementum, enim purus lacinia erat, eget gravida lectus ex sed dolor. Maecenas non neque eu nisi fringilla ornare. Fusce odio neque, volutpat in felis sed, consequat mattis leo. Praesent et mauris euismod, fringilla ipsum in, dignissim nisl. Duis quis lacus at nulla semper semper.

Cras massa mauris, mattis ac lorem ac, tempor eleifend est. Donec gravida tincidunt tristique. Nam semper id odio id viverra. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam eu sagittis arcu, ut pretium elit. Pellentesque id elit eu ex rutrum cursus vitae et metus. Sed enim leo, mollis non malesuada quis, imperdiet sed mi. Vestibulum pretium, augue a hendrerit hendrerit, quam est accumsan leo, at accumsan nulla diam sed justo.

Pellentesque ut lacus gravida, scelerisque massa vel, venenatis sapien. Integer id justo a augue rutrum pellentesque ac efficitur ex. Cras interdum enim quis libero tempor faucibus. Vivamus eu diam eu sapien ultricies vestibulum. Ut consequat felis at ligula dictum rutrum. Sed eget ullamcorper leo, vitae sodales justo. Pellentesque nec tellus felis. Aenean augue sem, tristique consequat magna a, efficitur ultrices ligula.</p>
```

Comment: the navbar not fixed

Comment: I had to remove the class `.navbar-fixed-top` because that fixes it to the top always and what you want, I assume, is for it to become fixed only when you scroll past the image/logo. Works for me in Chrome, Firefox, Edge. Haven't tried in other browsers.